# Having trouble with many to many association nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am getting this error `ActiveRecord::unknown attribute: store` from dealcontroller,I am pretty sure has something to do with this line
`@deal=@city.deals.build(params[:deal])` is this correct for nested form?This is what i have.

```
   class dealController < ApplicationController
   def create
   @city = City.find(session[:city_id])
   @deal=@city.deals.build(params[:deal])
   if @deal.save
   flash[:notice]="successfully created"
   redirect_to @deal
    else
   render 'new'    
   end 
   end
   end
```

deal model

```
    class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :city
has_many :stores ,:through =>:store_deals
has_many :store_deals
accepts_nested_attributes_for :store_deals
    end
```

store model

```
    class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :deals ,:through =>:store_deals
has_many :store_deals
    end
```

store-deal model

```
    class StoreDeal < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :store
belongs_to :deal

    end
```

city model

```
     class City < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :deals 
     end
```

view

```
 <%= form_for @deal ,:url=>{:action =>"create"} do |f|%>

  <%= f.text_field :item_name %><br/>

  <%=f.fields_for :store_deal do |s| %>
  <%=s.text_field :store_name %>
  <%end%>
  <%= f.submit "post"%>

<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not wrong (nested forms always give me headaches) it should better look like that :

**model**

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :stores ,:through =>:store_deals
  has_many :store_deals
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stores
end
```

**controller**

```
def new
  @city = City.find(session[:city_id])
  @deal = @city.deals.build
  @deal.stores.build
end

def create
  @city = City.find(session[:city_id])
  @deal = @city.deals.build(params[:deal])

  # etc.
end
```

**view**

```
<%= form_for @deal ,:url=>{:action =>"create"} do |f|%>
  <%= f.text_field :item_name %><br/>
  <%= f.fields_for :stores do |s| %>
    <%= s.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "post" %>
<% end %>
```

detailed information available [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for). There is also a [Railscasts example](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)